# Using array to determine status on a given date in BigQuery/Standard SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

For each day of the calendar year, I need to check the status of a record, and mark it as 1 or 0 depending on the status (Published =1, else 0). The status is in an array attached to each record.

I joined the table with the records and arrays to a table with a calendar containing dates for each day of a given year.

```
`select
cdate,
YYYYMM,
_id,
createdat,
case when cdate>=statushistory.date and <statushistory.date and statushistory.status="Published" then 1 else 0 end as active,
statushistory
from bigquery.calendar 
join rs.listings on extract(date from createdat)<=cdate, unnest(statushistory)
where _id ="HGk5HMd6ZxmSRgEJ6"
;`
```

I am stuck. I can't reference the specific fields within `statushistory`: `statushistory.status`, and `statushistory.date`. When I try to reference them, it gives me the error that they are in an array.

Even if I knew how to reference them, I need to place `cdate` in between the correct two `statushistory.date` to determine the status.

The _id referenced above has 4 status and 4 dates.

My goal is to create 1 if status was "Published" during `cdate`

[image]

Comment: it is not clear - what is expected output. provide some more examples of input and respective expected output - otherwise the answers will be more like shooting in the air

Comment: Desired output is cdate, _id, and binary (1 or 0) for status Published or Paused, respectively. I apologize, first time using stackoverlow

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear on exactly what you want to do.  However, I suspect it has to do with getting the status on each date.

If so, you can `unnest` in a subquery:

```
select c.cdate, c.YYYYMM, l._id, l.createdat,
       (select sh.status
        from unnest(l.statushistory) sh
        where c.cdate >= sh.date and 
              c.cdate <= sh.date
       ) as status_on_date
from bigquery.calendar c join
     rs.listings l
     on extract(date from l.createdat)<= c.cdate 
where l._id = 'HGk5HMd6ZxmSRgEJ6'
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is a step in the right direction. This marks cdate as Publised or Paused on the date it was published or paused. Now I need to fill in the blanks...I think I can figure that part out. Thank you!